# how to call up a kohen/levi as acharon

Tags: minhag, kohen-priest, torah-service, shulchan-aruch, levites-leviyim

*Shulachan Aruch* (*OC* 135:10) holds, and [*Rama* (there)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=34) seems to also hold, that if a *kohen* (or *levi*, m.m.) is called as *acharon* then the *gabai* should say "*af al pi shehu kohen*". The purpose of this is to announce that he's a *kohen*, so people don't think he's an invalid *kohen*. Do any *Ashk'nazim* use this wording, as opposed to saying just "*p'loni ben p'loni hakohen*"?

Comment: I've never heard that... I've always heard him called "ya'amod, ploni ben ploni, kohen acharon"

Comment: @JoelSpolsky, me, too. (Well, "_yaamod p'loni ben p'loni hakohen acharon_", I think, but whatever.)

Comment: Do we know if in the shulchan aruch's time and place a Kohen was called up so 'n' so hakohen?  Perhaps hakohen was not part of the formal title, which would lead people to believe he was not a kohen since he was called after a yisrael.   Therefore, the chazan would announce before his aliyah "even though he is a kohen.  We add hakohen to the title, which would take care of the issue.  (No proofs, so no answer.)

Comment: @YDK, you're right that that's the reason to say "_af al pi_...": more specifically, the concern is that people who know he's a _kohen_ will think he's _pagum_ (_SA_ :8–9, _MB_ :32). I think _MB_ :33 seems to imply that the exact wording doesn't matter, so long as we mention he's a _kohen_. My question is really about the wording employed by the _SA_: I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: Aruch Hashulchan does mention that the whole "af-al-pi shehu kohen" thing is unnecessary, but that people seem to do it anyway. In my experience, adding *aliyos* to a parsha in the first place is very rare, let alone calling up a kohen for one. But I guess the same applies to calling a kohen for maftir, which is more common.

Comment: @jake, adding _aliyos_ is very rare in some synagogues and unheard of (except on _Simchas Tora_) in others, but very common in yet others. I was in a Bobov synagogue once where the reading was stopped every three _p'sukim_ (where the _s'sumos_ and _p'suchos_ allowed it) for an _aliya_.

Comment: May I suggest that the Shulchan Aruch there does not only refer to Acharon but also to a kohen called up any time other than first. I was called up once for revii or chamishi in a Sefardi shul "af al pi shehu kohen".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: Right. I mentioned that the _SA_ says it about _acharon_ (even though he says it more generally) because I wanted to add that the _Rama_ seems to agree (which is only about _acharon_).

Answer (score 2):

In regard to the "af-al-pi shehu kohen", we are Ashkenazim and my husband is a Cohen.  Some years ago we spent Shabbat in Venice, Italy.  By the time they got around to asking my husband who he was, they had already passed Cohen.  So they said, "No problem."  They called him up as Chamishi, with the addendum of "af-al-pi..."  So here's a case of not even being Acharon.  Don't know if Italian minhagim are that different from Sephardic, in general, in this practice.

Comment: +1, many thanks. As you note, though, this seems to be according to the Sephardic custom, in that it follows the _Shulchan Aruch_ which allows a _kohen_ as the fifth man.